# Redirect from missing page to correct webpage php

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404

I want to forward users from www.example.com/about to www.example.com/about.php.
I do not want to use a .htaccess file. This is on a linux server.

Thank you

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `header('Location: www.example.com/about.php')` for redirection

Comment: Why wouldn't you want a .htaccess to do this? You could rewrite the URL. If you want a PHP redirect, you would need a *folder* called 'about', with an index-file that redirects to `../about.php`, that seems rather difficult and more cluttering than a URL rewrite

Comment: @zarawayun - i need to redirect from non-existent pages (so there's no good place to put that code

Comment: I want to use apache configuration, not .htaccess or php on multiple pages

Answer (score 0):

Without using a `.htaccess` file you would have to allow the `.php` url load and redirect based on the current url of the page using PHP.

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ($path_parts['extension'] === "php") {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php', '');
}
```

Depending on your needs, i.e. if `.php` pages have already been indexed by crawlers/bots on the internet then you may need to add a `301 Moved Permanently` header as well.

Comment: Put this code at the top of your php files. Bearing in mind you cannot redirect from non existent pages using PHP, that is server control, i.e, Apache .htaccess